# Javascript IIFE anonymous function

Tags: javascript, iife

I've been trying to understand exactly how IIFEs work in regards to anonymous functions. I understand their use in avoiding global variable collisions and that they create their own local scope.

I'm not clear on what happens when an anonymous function like this is called.

```
(function () {
  var myVar = 'foo';
  }
)()
```

If this is immediately invoked and it is not available in the global scope, where is it available? How would I access myVar?

Comment: you cannot access to myVar, IIFE work as a well protected singleton

Comment: You won't access it unless you make it a property of `window` or something else in the scope above.

Comment: Would that mean passing in (window) to the invoking parenthesis?

Comment: @byrdr No, but you could, it will help minification. You would need to do `window.myVar` in either case.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. So unless I explicitly define access to something like "window" they will not be accessible on their own.

Comment: Yes - that, in fact is one of the reasons you'd write code like that: to protect the global namespace from pollution, so that your script won't step on variables used by other scripts, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

This notation is known as module pattern

```
var myModule = function () {
      var privateVar = "foo";
      function privateMethod() {
       return "bar";

      }

      return {
        publicMethod : function(){
          return 'foo';
        }
      }
}
```

To make this module completely isolated from the global scope, we can close it in a IIFE

```
(function (setUp) {
      var privateVar = setUp;
      function privateMethod() {
       return "bar";

      }

      return {
        publicMethod : function(){
          return 'foo';
        }
      }
})(window.setUp);
```